# link to image url works, but not to show this image

Tags: java, html, image, hyperlink, referer

In a Java program, I have a link to one of my shared pics. The link is working, but the picture will not be shown. I tried the code in a html file. There is the same behavior. If I use a general image like the chip logo, than it works. So I assume the problem is the special link referer!? Any idea, how I it can work?

This is my generated test code:

```
<a href="https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AEUxxUA0VvArz2g&cid=4292473ABC84F877&id=4292473ABC84F877%21137&parId=4292473ABC84F877%21134&o=OneUp"> <img src="https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AEUxxUA0VvArz2g&cid=4292473ABC84F877&id=4292473ABC84F877%21137&parId=4292473ABC84F877%21134&o=OneUp" width="400" height="400" border="0" alt="I can't see the picture, but the link is working. Please click this picture."></a>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: put your sample java code

Answer (score 1):

That is not the link to the image, but to some Onedrive magic. The actual url would be like:

```
https://0ejrxa-sn3301.files.1drv.com/y3mlE_XxWo_5ZiWLGCrIsW6J41xdYgdpu_JZH5-HBcVCTO5jswuWF63Zok314nIAXNvBlkVdjVJmIPLw6LxLLhaQcM1ClesV0FBVOIg3FzPhUVUhYbz80jiLCEgBxpOUgEtBU7v_f3CB7ZFfIePdq9SwlzjwyJfb-Ko2Yn-m_XXfMs/IMG_20170123_140426.jpg?psid=1
```

Which I found by clicking "View original".

Comment: Best solution, depending on your goals. The link behind the image will show original image embedded in the onedrive image viewer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't changed my href link. So it's equal to the solution from @Leozeo in the post before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide path to actual image file.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://0eib2w-dm2306.files.1drv.com/y3mZmtCgaPDWzwwO--MruAzJQrmzG7opNsvntq8tXXQWAzw17rMogruog8h9v0iQSOPS7e8Bsz9YZAjF5smX8A_iaBNlHurOSGIAZZUnBYVjFJ2gIYf-NK2oqlI0C4A5rghoGpQbDfj4PoT3bnJhJgkr9NMSDNafKeVs7CImgwYeKo/IMG_20170120_151432.jpg?psid=1"> <img src="https://0eib2w-dm2306.files.1drv.com/y3mZmtCgaPDWzwwO--MruAzJQrmzG7opNsvntq8tXXQWAzw17rMogruog8h9v0iQSOPS7e8Bsz9YZAjF5smX8A_iaBNlHurOSGIAZZUnBYVjFJ2gIYf-NK2oqlI0C4A5rghoGpQbDfj4PoT3bnJhJgkr9NMSDNafKeVs7CImgwYeKo/IMG_20170120_151432.jpg?psid=1" width="400" height="400" border="0" alt="I can't see the picture, but the link is working. Please click this picture."></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best solution, depending on your goals. This show the image and the link behind the image will show only the original image. (See also comment below)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the .jpg or other image extension at the end of the link of the img.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right about the special link blocking the picture. When I clicked embed on the OneDrive site, it gave me the link below. Try replacing yours with that one.

https://0ejrxa-sn3301.files.1drv.com/y3miPUdFvpxMtYaHhFoXbG-SBHJLLOUs7XuBRB8LWs6X46i9XUIlIEGOk9aA9NOVYvxQ_dM4FzZv-zcBGrp2NaZyQDtFiCASeRPXOlKBBHDvV4F28rEYieMDSqFXiGEMt42c6-mdiKTUM8ypkbRdDRdtx5yeh0REvEq0fL2GErvmdPBbtqkrv75BJYK_CdkjWVl?width=4208&height=2368&cropmode=none

Comment: A third solution. The link behind the image will open the download dialog.